# Why can't I easily select which SATA drive to boot up into?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I am running a dell dimension 8400 with two SATA hard drives.

I have an operating system on each drive, and would like to boot up into whichever one I want.

When having both drives plugged in, pressing F12 for boot options only gives me one option other than booting from Floppy, CD, or USB. The option is simply boot from SATA.

One operating system is on SATA 0 and the other is on SATA 1. The only way I found possible to boot into the other operating system is to go into the BIOS and disable SATA 0 so it has to revert to the secondary SATA drive.

My BIOS is seems like there aren't many options, the version is A01. The only options regarding SATA drives include disabling/enabling SATA 0-3 and SATA operaton including allowing me to select one of these options:

•Raid Autodetect / AHCI
•Raid Autodect /ATA 
• RAID On 
•Combination *(SATA/PATA combination mode)*

Am I stuck with changing the BIOS every time I want to change my OS to boot into, or is there an easier way to choose the hard drive?

Comment: [Latest bios is A09](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R129671), may or may not give you what you need, bios updates are risky and in extreme cases can cause your pc to become inoperable without a way to repair it.

Comment: Which 2 operating systems do you have?

Comment: FreeDOS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest

- Updating you BIOS.

OR

- [Installing grub2](http://atagunov.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-grub2-without-linux.html) Bootloader. I'm not sure about the FreeDOS OS, but you can add it manually.

Comment: Thanks! Given that I only need freedos a few times per month I am probably going to live with going To the bios each time, but I will give grub2 a try when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Dell BIOS that I've seen have a section labeled Boot in which you choose which devices are bootable and in what order you want the search to go.  So if I say bootable devices are floppy A:, CD Drive, SATA 0, then I also have to specify in what order will it search - boot from floppy first, if no floppy, go to CD, then go to SATA 0 or whatever.  Try and look for this BIOS setting and then choose the SATA 0 and SATA 1 as boot devices, set whatever you want as your default order.  Then you MIGHT be able to F12 and choose a different device to boot from when you want to.

Comment: There is boot order, but only has one option -- SATA

Answer (score 0):

This is because the firmware defaults, like many computers, to assigning SATA0 (or the lowest port with a drive) to primary and all others to secondary.

I would recommend trying/booting [Super Grub 2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). This way you can verify that Grub can detect the necessary drives, and boot them, before going through the more tedious task of installing Grub.

I personally wouldn't bother with a BIOS update. Simply because there's plenty of other ways you can solve the issue at hand which involve absolutely no risk. Not to mention updating your BIOS only offers **potential** solutions. I'm willing to wager that even if you were able to successfully update your BIOS, you wouldn't notice any changes, much less the one you want.